# Implicitly Appending Scala XML Literals

Tags: xml, scala, append, literals, implicit

Scala's support for XML literals is fantastic for generating type safe XHTML markup; however, there's an annoying gotcha in that you must append literals together with the `++` operator when non-xml-literal code is included in a given block.

For example, this blows up:

```
import scala.xml._

def getNode() = <div>foo</div>
val node: NodeSeq = 
  <div>bar</div>
  <div>baz</div>{
    getNode()
  }

 error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.xml.Elem
 required: Int
  getNode()
```

and while the below compiles, notice how you have to `++` *after* the non-xml-literal `getNode()` call, otherwise only the tail `Elem` is generated.

```
import scala.xml._

def getNode() = <div>foo</div>
val node: NodeSeq = 
  <div>bar</div>
  <div>baz</div> ++ {
    getNode()
  }
  <div>lonely node</div>

node: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<div>bar</div>, <div>baz</div>, <div>foo</div>)
res6: scala.xml.Elem = <div>lonely node</div>
```

So, is there a way to implicitly chain XML literals interspersed with XML returning Scala code by default? As it stands you get a false sense of security when working with XML literals since the above example compiles but is effectively broken.

One way to explicitly force appending of literals would be to do something like:

```
import scala.xml._
def getNode() = <div>foo</div>
def nodify(elems: Elem*): NodeSeq = elems
nodify(
  <div>bar</div>,
  <div>baz</div>,
  getNode(),
  <div>not lonely node</div>
)

res8: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<div>bar</div>, <div>baz</div>, <div>foo</div>, <div>not lonely node</div>)
```

but that's not so nice in that you have to wrap the XML literal blocks in a method call. At least it force appends, won't compile without.

Would love to have a clean XHTML markup DSL, please provide the secret sauce if you've got it! (or clue me in if I'm missing something blindingly obvious).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way I know of to handle this type of situation is to wrap the expressions in the no-op `<xml:group/>` element:

```
import scala.xml._

def getNode() = <div>foo</div>

val node: NodeSeq = <xml:group>
  <div>bar</div>
  <div>baz</div>{
    getNode()
  }
</xml:group>
```

yields:

```
scala> node
res0: scala.xml.NodeSeq = 

<div>bar</div>
<div>baz</div><div>foo</div>
```

Comment: Turns out that this solution provides minimal syntactic noise while appearing to work reliably across various xml type combinations (Elems, NodeSeq, NodeBuffer, etc.). Thanks

Comment: Sorry, just came up with a solution using varargs that I just posted. All of the answers here are valid in their own right, so none will be checked ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As a refresher (for me), your braces are not an embedded Scala expression, which has to be content inside a tag.

Your error message says you're calling `NodeBuffer.apply{f}`, so that's the enhancement below.

When you have two Elements in a row, you get a `NodeBuffer`, and the compiler builds them with `&+`.

```
scala> import xml._
import xml._

scala> def f = <div>foo</div>
f: scala.xml.Elem

scala> implicit class `autoappend Elem`(b: NodeBuffer) { def apply(e: Elem) = b &+ e }
defined class autoappend$u0020Elem

scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val n =
<div>bar</div>
<div>baz</div>{
f
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

n: scala.xml.NodeBuffer = ArrayBuffer(<div>bar</div>, <div>baz</div>, <div>foo</div>)

scala> val nn: NodeSeq = n
nn: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<div>bar</div>, <div>baz</div>, <div>foo</div>)
```

You can still:

```
scala> n(1)
res0: scala.xml.Node = <div>baz</div>

scala> n(2)
res1: scala.xml.Node = <div>foo</div>
```

Doesn't everyone use interpolators these days? Is that a fad or a trend?

Answer (score 0):

So, after hacking around a bit I've discovered that the explicit approach using varargs is the way to go.

Check it out, for generating html markup you're usually doing so within a layout or partial, something like:

```
object Crud extends Layout{
  def apply[T <: Seq[Node]](title: String, args: (Symbol,String)*)(body: T*) {
    header(...)
    <body>
      {body}
    </body>
    footer(...)
  }
}
```

and then you want to implicitly chain the markup that comprises the body of above layout. As per above answers there's no elegant way to pull off implicit chaining. With var args however, you can have your cake and eat it too. Before implementing the varargs approach a form to create Foos looked like:

```
Crud(title, ...)(
  <h1>{title}</h1>
  <div>&nbsp;</div> ++
  withForm(routes.Foo.save)(
    fields(form) ++
    crud.submit("Create")
  ) ++
  css("foo") ++ 
  css("bar")    
)
```

with zero compile time guarantee that a ++ wasn't forgotten, totally error prone. With varargs as per above Crud apply signature foo form create looks like this:

```
Crud(title, ...)(
  <h1>{title}</h1>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>,
  withForm(routes.Foo.save)(
    fields(form),
    crud.submit("Create")
  ),
  css("foo"),
  css("bar")    
)
```

and if you omit a comma you get a compile time error, exactly what we want. On the "plus" side you can still use ++ if desired since Seq[Node] lies at the top of Scala XML type hierarchy, so Elem, NodeSeq, etc. doesn't matter, whatever it is it just has to derive from Seq[Node] and you're good to go, woohoo ;-)

Comment: Everything is easier with an expected type, and even easier if it's a function call. That's much different from the OP, which was a bare expression (for which I still like my appropriation of braces). For this use case, you could just write a macro that collects the Node expressions -- it's not relevant to the macro whether they represent literals or invocations. No punctuations or operators required.

Comment: I took a look, but as a by-name param, `(body: =>Unit)` or similar, it suffers the same parsing problems, you need a semi between xml and code. After that, the macro can assemble the `Elem`-valued parts of the block.

Comment: @som-snytt a no-punctuation-required macro would be elegant indeed, solves the entire problem. Writing that macro is another matter, have yet to go down macro road (seems to be constantly influx).